# MODx Revolution backend browser doesn`t display thumb images

Tags: backend, modx-revolution

After I`m trying to put an image to my TV or whatsoever I see only empty gif images instead of thumb images. 
Well let me describe my problem with [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqdOX.jpg)! Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete all the "hidden" .image.jpg images that is inside the picture folder. That way MODX will generate new thumbs.